# Xamarin.Forms app crashes when selecting text from custom label on Android

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms

Iv'e created an app in Xamarin.Forms and then created a custom lable with a custom renderer for android. The renderer's job is to make the label text selectable. And it works, the label text is now selectable. The problem is, while it works perfectly with regular lables, when i try to select text in a label which has both Hebrew and English (RTL and LTR) text, the app crashes and I get this error:
Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 'length=35; index=35' (indexes and length vary between crashes but are always equal to each other).

I looked online for a solution and couldn't find one... I also tried other implementations of the renderer and they all had the same error. (I think it might be a problem with Android/Xamarin)
Can someone help me?

Code for renderer:

```
class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {}
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
}
```

(Custom label (SELabel) has no code, it just inherits from the regular Label)

Device Logs:
[Log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XXbt40FulM45Feqh3PeNdM_DglSzWVi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The error may be that some languages uses more than one byte to represent a char. I am sorry that i can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

I use google translation "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms" to Hebrew "ברוך הבא ל - Xamarin.Forms.". And make a code sample to test on my side. It works well. Please check my code.

SELabel:

```
public class SELabel:Label
{
}
```

CustomLabelRenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SELabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace SelectableLabel.Droid
{
public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <local:SELabel
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms! Hebrew: ברוך הבא ל - Xamarin.Forms."
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

You could download the source file from the GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/SelectableLabel

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i did though... could you try this text and see if it crashes: "אגרת לקראת פתיחת שנת הלימודים \nאגרת של מנהלת בית הספר לקראת פתיחת שנת הלימודים – קישור\n(https://handasaim.co.il/2017/06/12/%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%93%d7%a2-%d7%9b%d7%9c%d7%9c%d7%99-%d7%93%d7%91%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%a0%d7%94%d7%9c%d7%aa/)\n" (try to select the link)

Comment: I test the text you provided. It works well on my side. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/YVkUn5i You could test the text with my project.